# How to delete multiple tables simultaneously Sqlite + Ionic2

Tags: sqlite, ionic2

I want to delete multiple tables in a single SQL query in Sqlite. Is it possible. Can I use Sqlbatch for this and how? I have no idea how to do this. Please help.

Basically I want to remove all the tables in db to reset it.

Comment: @RyanVincent, can you please guide me how to do it inside Ionic2 code.

Comment: @RyanVincent - it's not 'just a text file' but for the rest you are right.

Comment: Everything OK, but how can I delete the sqlite db/file , from my ionic2 code?

Comment: Yes, it is _like_ a text file. But even more important to make sure it's closed before deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Start by getting the names of all your tables from sqlite_master

```
select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table'
```

Then create `drop table` statements using the table names and execute them using sqlBatch or individual executeSql statements,